# Importing .sql file into MongoDB, iterating this action 1000 times

Tags: linux, mongodb, scripting, multiplatform

I need to do several test with a large file in mongoDB.
But my test data is in .sql format and only of 2MB.

I need a way to generate a 2GB input file and I thought two ways:

- Generate a 2GB file from the 2MB one, using some Linux magic.
- Iterate the input instruction 1000 times.

I don't know in which OS MongoDB will run, so a multiplatform solution is preferred. 
Which way is better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script, read `inputfile.txt` and append it into `outputfile.txt` until it reach a size of `2GB`.

```
 filename_in="inputfile.txt"  
 filename_out="outputfile.txt" 
 size="2000000000"       #2GB
 echo > $filename_out
 while [  $(stat -c%s "$filename_out") -lt "$size" ]; do
      echo file size =  $(stat -c%s "$filename_out")
      cat $filename_in >> $filename_out
done
```